# Chain Javascript function before promise function to only call based on initial function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, es6-promise

Consider the following code that works correctly (functions below are normally inside `API` object):

```js
let Query = async function( method, endpoint, options, successCode, obKey ){

    return true;
    //return new Error( 'Could not complete query!' );
    
};

let isAlive = async function( options ){
 try {
  return await Query( 'GET', '/heart', options, 204 );
 } catch( error ){
  return error;
 }
};

let getNetworks = async function(options) {
 try {
  return await Query( 'GET', '/networks', options, 200, 'networks' );
 } catch( error ){
  return error;
 }
};

// Standard promise method works
isAlive().then( () => {
  getNetworks().then( result => {
   console.log( 'GET NETWORKS', result );
  }).catch( error => {
   console.log( 'GET NETWORKS ERROR', error.message );
  });
 }
);

// BUT to make for cleaner code base, how can I only call next function in chain
// based on isAlive() function?
```

How can I handle the `isAlive()` function to allow for chaining, but only to execute the Promise based functions that are called after `isAlive()` based on result in `isAlive()`, like below?

```
isAlive().getNetworks().then( result => {
    console.log( 'GET HOMIE NETWORKS', result );
}).catch( error => {
    console.log( 'GET HOMIE NETWORKS ERROR', error.message );
});
```

Yes I understand it could be done this way from inside an `async` function, however, there will be times where `await isAlive();` would not be possible ... and was hoping to be able to create an easy helper function that can be chained onto ... is this possible at all?  Without having to use `.then( ()=> { ... } )`?

Glot.IO: https://glot.io/snippets/exas8rbxyu
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tripflex/sj78297k/

I was able to figure out some basic chaining by returning `this`, but not sure how to implement something like this with Promises.

```js
var myObj = {
 hasPerms: false,
 check : function( doChain ){
     this.hasPerms = doChain;
  console.log( 'Checkinnngggg...' );
  return this;
 },
 then : function( callback ){
     if( this.hasPerms ){
         callback();
     } else {
         return false;
     }
 }
};

//"chain, chain, chain..."
myObj.check( false ).then( function(){
    console.log( 'I GOT FOO\'D');
});
```

Comment: `return await fn()` is never needed.  Just do `return fn()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you can just pass the function reference to the `then` method:

```
isAlive().then(getNetworks).then( result => {
    console.log( 'GET NETWORKS', result );
}).catch( error => {
    console.log( 'GET NETWORKS ERROR', error.message );
});
```

It is indeed a good practice to try to avoid nested promises, but instead return each promise to the outer promise chain.

Comment: Also worth noting that the way `isAlive()` is coded, it never rejects so a `.catch()` is never used.  But, perhaps that is a mistake in how `isAlive()` is written.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method on the `Promise` prototype, though you would need to use `.then()` within the method

```
Promise.prototype.getNetworks = function(value) {
  // do stuff
  return this.then(function(data) {
    // do stuff
    return data
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    throw err
  })
};
```

you could then use the pattern

```
isAlive().getNetworks();
```

Answer (score 0):

see if this can help

```
async function myFunc() {
throw new Error("Whoops!");
}
```

and here in the call, you can catch the error (reject)

```
myFunc()
.catch(function(rej, resolve)
   {console.log(`in the catch block rej ${rej}`
)});
```